# Largest subset of lines with two unique columns

Tags: algorithm, text, text-files

Given a text file with two columns, produce the largest possible subset of lines for which no value is repeated within either column.
For example, given these four lines :

```
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b
```

One can use something like "sort -u" on the command line, to unique first on column 1, leaving

```
1 a
2 a
```

and then on column two, leaving just

```
1 a
```

This satisfies "no value is repeated" but not "largest possible subset"
In an ideal world, I would have produced either

```
1 a
2 b
```

or

```
1 b
2 a
```

Given the further constraint that these files might be many gigabytes (i.e. much larger than available RAM, but much smaller than available disk), I can't just keep all the values in a data structure.

Can anyone think of an approach?

I would also be happy with "a pretty large subset", if I can't literally get "the largest possible subset"

If I sort by (column 1 ascending and then column 2 random), uniq'ing on column 1 will give me slightly better results, but I feel like there's something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: You aren't missing something simple. What you have is a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), and what you're looking for is a [maximal matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching).

Answer (score -1):

For each unique item from col 1 create a list of unique items from col 2. Then starting with the smallest of lists build the final output by taking first value from each list and each col-1-item, that has not been used in the output yet.